# Python Django: Minimal Django + Cassandra local application

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cassandra

I am trying to put together a minimum Django application that uses Cassandra as the database.

Here is what I tried:

1. Started a brand new Django project in PyCharm. Checked that `python manage.py runserver` works as expected.
2. Installed Cassandra using the instructions [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging). I had to change the `rpc_port` and `storage_port` to numbers lower than 9000 to get this to work (probably something to do with my firewall).  Cassandra is running, and I am able to execute instructions using `cqlsh`.
3. Installed [`cassandra-django-engine`](http://r4fek.github.io/django-cassandra-engine/).
4. Made the following changes to the `settings.py` file:

   - Added `django_cassandra_engine` to the front of the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple:

     ```
     INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django_cassandra_engine',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     )
     ```
   - Replaced SQLite as the database to Cassandra, like so:

     ```
     DATABASES = {
        'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
          'NAME': 'db',
          'TEST_NAME': 'test_db',
          'HOST': 'localhost',
          'PORT': '8160',
          'OPTIONS': {
            'replication': {
            'strategy_class': 'SimpleStrategy',
            'replication_factor': 1
           }
         }
       }
     }
     ```

     Note that this is the part that I am least sure about. I could not figure out, based on the documentation what the parameters `NAME` and `TEST_NAME` are supposed to be. Note also that I have added a `'PORT'` key and that the port number defaults to `9160` but I have changed it to `8160` for the reasons mentioned above. Not sure I need to add this key.

## Error information:

Here is a full traceback of the error from running a `python manage.py runserver` with the above project. Note that there are no apps defined in the project yet.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py:238: RemovedInDjango19Warning: In Django 1.9 the TEST_NAME connection setting will be moved to a NAME entry in the TEST setting
  self.prepare_test_settings(alias)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cassandra/util.py:486: UserWarning: The blist library is not available, so a pure python list-based set will be used in place of blist.sortedset for set collection values. You can find the blist library here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/
  "The blist library is not available, so a pure python list-based set will "

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django_cassandra_engine/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from uwsgidecorators import postfork
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/uwsgidecorators.py", line 10, in <module>
    import uwsgi
ImportError: No module named 'uwsgi'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django_cassandra_engine/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    cassandra_connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django_cassandra_engine/base/__init__.py", line 94, in connect
    self.connection = CassandraConnection(**settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django_cassandra_engine/connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django_cassandra_engine/connection.py", line 59, in setup
    connection.setup(self.hosts, self.keyspace, **self.connection_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 129, in setup
    session = cluster.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 755, in connect
    self.control_connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1868, in connect
    self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1903, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'localhost': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',)})
```

From what I can understand,
1. There is a top level `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: No module named 'uwsgi'
```

2. And there is a nested error:

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'localhost': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',)})
```

I am not sure which one of the two above is the more relevant error, and how to resolve the error in either case. Note that I have installed both the modules `uwsgi` and `uwsgidecorators`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the answer was fairly straightforward. Yes, a `'PORT'` key is required (actually a `'port'` key), but it goes into the `'connection'` setting, and is set to the `storage_port` and not to the `rpc_port`. Once I make these changes, the Django server runs cleanly.

Comment: Can you elaborate you answer. I am facing a similar issue